# Как установить версию проекта с помощью перехватчиков git?

Tags: git, githooks

Номер версии должен формироваться по шаблону MAJOR.MAJOR.PATCH.BUILD

Надо инкрементировать BUILD при объединении ветки feature в ветку develop

Проблемы при написании bash скрипта

**UPD**

```
#!/bin/bash

path="../../version.txt"

source $path
major1=$(echo $version | cut -f1 -d.)
major2=$(echo $version | cut -f2 -d.)
minor=$(echo $version | cut -f3 -d.)
build=$(echo $version | cut -f4 -d.)
build=$((build+1))
> $path
version="version=$major1.$major2.$minor.$build"
echo "$version" >> $path
echo $build
```

Скрипт так написал (первый раз пишу), теперь как сделать чтобы при объединении в develop инкрементировал?

Comment: какие именно проблемы? `переменная=$((переменная+1))`? уточните, нажав [edit]

Comment: вот эта строчка: `> $path` что по-вашему должна делать?

Comment: очищает файл version.txt,  просто не нашел как перезаписать значение

Comment: 1. проще удалить файл. 2. ещё проще не добавлять строку в файл, а сразу перезаписать — не `команда >> файл`, а `команда > файл` 3. а чтобы перенаправить вывод команды в файл, надо как минимум указать команду. если вам нравится именно такой способ (очистка содержимого вместо удаления), то можете использовать встроенную команду `:` (двоеточие). типа: `: > файл`

Comment: ок, а с гитом как быть? если в pre-commit писать то он будет инкрементировать когда коммит выполняется, а мне нужно когда сливаю ветку в develop

Comment: скорее всего, это невозможно. но попробуйте задать вопрос именно про то, **как автоматически внести исправление в файл при git merge** (опустив все эти детали про оболочку, скрипты, версии и т.д. и т.п.)

Comment: ещё один существенный момент, который всплыл во время раздумий: а вот этот файл, который вы собираетесь изменять, он вообще-то находится под контролем версий, или «просто так где-то лежит»?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, *...надо как минимум указать команду.* Что ты несёшь? Указанное в скрипте равносильно `truncate -s0`: http://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-empty-or-truncate-files-in-linux/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102714/how-would-i-write-a-pre-merge-hook-in-git

Comment: Вопрос, этот баш скрипт работает на windows?

Answer (score 1):

во-первых, по поводу инкрементации числа, отделённого от остального содержимого строки символом точка. в posix-совместимой оболочке это можно сделать, например, так:

```
$ v=blablabla.10; echo "${v%.*}.$((${v##*.}+1))"
blablbabla.11
```

если строка хранится, например, в файле:

```
$ echo blablabla.100500 > файл
```

то инкрементировать число в этом файле можно, например, так:

```
$ v=$(cat файл); echo "${v%.*}.$((${v##*.}+1))" > файл
```

проверяем:

```
$ cat файл
blablabla.100501
```

---

во-вторых, по поводу перехватчика (*hook*). единственным подходящим является *post-merge*. выполняется он после слияния.

имя ветки, из которой происходило слияние, насколько я вижу, встречается в переменной окружения `GIT_REFLOG_ACTION` в виде `merge имя-ветки`.

текущую ветку можно получить из файла `.git/HEAD`. она там будет записана в виде `ref: refs/heads/имя-ветки`.

таким образом, перехватчик *post-merge* должен выглядеть примерно так (подставлены имена веток из вопроса):

```
#!/bin/bash -e

from="feature"
to="develop"

if [ "$GIT_REFLOG_ACTION" = "merge $from" ] && \
  [ "$(cat .git/HEAD)" = "ref: refs/heads/$to" ]; then
  echo "делаем то, что требуется" >&2
fi
```

вот внутрь условного оператора и можно вставить требуемую функциональность.

если файл с версией находится под управлением *git-а*, то после его изменения можно сделать и коммит примерно так:

```
v=$(cat файл); v="${v%.*}.$((${v##*.}+1))"; echo "$v" > файл
git add файл && git commit -m "сделали инкремент до версии $v"
```